# IsEmailConfirmedAsync has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using `MVC 5`'s scaffold-ed code that generates a `login` method. I followed the official tutorial from...

[Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset)

...to add the additional functionality of making sure email is confirmed before user can log in to the system.

The following is my code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var currentUser = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(currentUser.Id))
        {
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

    // Other scaffolded implementations
}
```

However, Visual Studio comes up with an error that states that the argument is invalid for the method `IsEmailConfirmedAsync`. Apparently, I checked and the `currentUser.Id` is an `int` datatype and is the `id` for the `System.Threading.Task`. How do I fix this so that what I pass is the `UserId` instead of the Task `Id`?

Comment: Try currentUser.Result.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya No, you should not access `.Result`. What if the async call hasn't completed by the time you reach that line and you try to access `.Result`?

Comment: Why are you not awaiting the results of `UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email)`?

Comment: You are right @mason. To use result the FindByNameAsync should be called with await. Using model.Email is good idea but I think author wants to check existence of email first.

Comment: @Pow4Pow5, That is because in your code `currentUser` is assigned the `Task` returned from finding the user. You should await that call to get the desired user `var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because in your code `currentUser` is being assigned the `Task` returned from finding the user.

You should await that call to get the desired behavior

```
var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

Even the example linked to the OP has it that way

```
// Require the user to have a confirmed email before they can log on.
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
if (user != null)
{
   if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
   {
      ViewBag.errorMessage = "You must have a confirmed email to log on.";
      return View("Error");
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe i made a stupid mistake not noticing the missing ``await`` keyword.. Thank you for your answer!